# Django: upload image can't find uploaded image

Tags: django, image, upload, find

I have already tried searching stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything. My problem is that I cannot seem to find the folder where the pictures I upload is supposed to be. Seems like everything else works?

Here you can see my code:

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("Form is valid")
            return redirect('/questions/profile')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm(instance=request.user)
     return render(request, 'questions/model_form_upload.html', {
       'form': form
})
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^upload/$', views.model_form_upload, name='upload')
```

Models.py

```
import os

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
     return os.path.join('users/', str(instance.id), filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_image_path, 
    blank=True, null=True)
```

Forms.py

```
from questions.models import Document

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('profile_image',)
```

model_form_upload.html

```
 {% extends 'questions/base.html' %}

 {% block content %}
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>

 <p><a href="{% url 'questions:profile' %}">Return to profile</a></p>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Each file should be under `/path/to/project/media/users/id/`. No?

Comment: Yes, but there has not been created a media folder, or a folder at all when I have "successfully" uploaded it. Shoudn't there?

Comment: You should create this by yourself. Django, will not automatically create this for you.

Comment: Okay so if I create it, it is beside the different apps. But it still doesn't work. I actually think it was created by itself last time I did it.

Comment: please add traceback of error.

Comment: There is not actually an error. It just doesn't get saved..